# Graph with a vertex of infinite degree elementary equiv. with a graph with vertices of arbitrarily large finite degree

Tags: graph-theory, model-theory

I want to prove that :
Given a graph $G$ with vertices of arbitrarily large finite degree, there is a graph elementary equivalent to $G$ that contains a vertex of infinite degree.
(the degree of a vertex is $n$ if it is connected with $n$ other vertices)
I've tried this way :
Let $\Sigma = EDiag(G) \cup \{deg(v) > n | n \in \omega\}$ where $v$ is a new symbol of constant. Every finite $\Sigma_0 \subset \Sigma$ is satisfied by an expantion of G, hence, for Compactness theorem, $\Sigma$ is satisfiable; so there is a model for $\Sigma$ i.e. a graph $G_1$ with a vertex of infinite degree and such that $G$ elementary embeds in $G_1$.
I don't know how to find the other elementary embedding or how to prove that $Th(G) = Th(G_1)$. Is even the first part correct?

Comment: Your proof seems fine to me - I don't understand your questions. 1. What is "the other elementary embedding" you're looking for? 2. Is it not clear to you that if there is an elementary embedding $M\to N$, then $\mathrm{Th}(M) = \mathrm{Th}(N)$?

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the theory. I thought that if there is an elementary embedding $\pi : M \to N$ then $M \vDash \phi[a] \Rightarrow N \vDash \phi[\pi(a)]$ so $Th(M) \subset  Th(M)$ so i need an elementary embedding from N to M.

Comment: Once you have that $M\models \phi$ implies $N\models\phi$ for all sentences $\phi$, you automatically have the converse implication, i.e., you automatically have elementary equivalence.  The reason is that, if $N\models\phi$ then it cannot be the case that $M\models\neg\phi$, since that would imply $N\models\neg\phi$ (by applying what you already know to the sentence $\neg\phi$).  So it must be the case that $M\models\phi$.